# Simplifying .click function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick, conditional-statements, show

Say I have a `<label>` tag with an id of `#trigger`, which should trigger `.hide();` event for element `.target` on click. Clicking on any other element except `#trigger` should show `.target` again. Here is my code, which works but I feel that it could be simplified.

```
$('ul#category li label#trigger').click(function() {
    $('.target').hide(500);
});
$('ul#category li label:not(#trigger)').click(function() {
    $('.target').show(500);
});
```

I'm thinking this could be simplified with a conditional?

Comment: Since IDs must be unique, `ul#category li label#trigger` can reduce to `#trigger`, and `ul#category li label:not(#trigger)` can reduce to `:not(#trigger)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not animating the show/hide action is not a problem you can use the `toggle` method which accepts a boolean value:

```
$('ul#category li label').click(function() {
     $('.target').toggle(this.id !== 'trigger');
});
```

Another option is:

```
var $target = $('.target');

$('ul#category li label').click(function() {
    var method = this.id === 'trigger' ? 'hide' : 'show';
    $target[method](500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to see if you are not clicking on `#target` or its children hide target else show.

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    var that = $(e.target);
    if(that.prop('id')!='trigger' || that.closest('#trigger').length===0){
       $('.target').show(500);
    }else{
        $('.target').hide(500);
    }
});
```

Updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vd8ddgra/1/